What's the relation between Chaos and the Life Spirits?
According to the Nanatsu no Taizai wikia,

Chaos「混沌」 is an ancient, preeminent entity that created the world, the five races and even the gods out of nothingness.

Chaos
but also according to the wikia,
Life Spirits

Life Spirits「生命いのちの精霊」 are beings with no shape or individuality that
are described as "pieces of their Great One"「“大いなる者の一端なり”, Ōinaru Mono
no Ippashinari」 and the font of energy that raises all races in many
worlds, including Humans, Demons, Goddesses, Giants, and Fairies.

So Chaos created all the races, but their energy comes from the Life Spirits, who apparently have no relation with him but with "their Great One". How does this work?
What's the relation between Chaos and the Life Spirits?
